# Exact computation of Bayes factor for multivariate normal

Tags: bayesian, references, model-selection, computational-statistics, bic

**Question:** Is there a known, exact expression for the Bayes factor between two multivariate normal hypotheses?

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be two subsets of $R^d$ with normal priors $\pi(\mu|H_j)$. The sets $H_j$ represent two hypotheses for the unknown mean $\mu$.

The Bayes factor is defined as $BF=P(X|H_1)/P(X|H_2)$, where $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is an iid sample from a multivariate normal $N(\mu,\Sigma)$. Each $X_i$ is $d$-dimensional. In this expression,
$$
P(X|H_j)
= \int P(X|\mu,H_j)\pi(\mu|H_j)\,d\mu.
$$
A common example of $H_j$ is $H_1 : \mu_1=0$ and $H_2=R^d$, so we are testing if the first coordinate of the mean is zero. It is clear that this is just the integral of a normal PDF, so it can be calculated analytically.

In principle I could do this myself, but it seems quite tedious, and I just need to know the eventual formula. I have not been able to find a reference for this, which is surprising given how standard this is.

**Clarification:** For general $H_j$, this is probably intractable, but I only need the formula when $H_j$ are defined by coordinate zeroes as in the example.

Comment: Our [book](http://amzn.to/2kxP1vO) (p.81) contains illustrations for the multivariate case, when using conjugate (Zellner) priors.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Do you know of a reference for general normal priors?

Comment: If only the mean $\mu$ is  unknown, it works for any Normal prior.

Comment: I appreciate the reference, although I will point out for future readers that it does not directly answer my question about the general normal case. There are some steps involved to go from your setting to the general case. Now, I don't think it would be too hard, but it's worth pointing out.

Comment: Your hypotheses are well fitted for a t-test or a F-test (especially in case of linear model) and if the stnadard deviation is unknown. There are some results that show that your bayes factor is equal to a confluent hypergeometric function in some cases and it does not depend on the prior. I drop here some references:

S. Rushton. “On a Sequential t-Test”. In: Oxford University Press on behalf of Biometrika
Trust 37.3/4 (1950), pp. 326–333.
54

Comment: [19] S. Rushton. “On a Two-Sided Sequential t-Test”. In: Oxford University Press on behalf
of Biometrika Trust 39.3/4 (1952), pp. 302–308.

[20] S. Rushton. “On certain sequential test of composite hypotheses”. P.h.D thesis. London:
University of London, 1952.

[21] S. Rushton. “On the Confluent Hypergeometric function M(α, γ, x)”. In: The Indian
Journal of Statistics(1933-1960) 13.4 (1954), pp. 369–376.